# XCode7.2.1 keep crash with these errors below

Tags: xcode, crash

***Please check my bellow answer( about the carthage), may be help you to solve this kind of error.***

Any idea to resolve? I have already removed the XCode in application and reinstalled it from App Store, it didn't work.

```
Process:               Xcode [71913]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               7.2.1 (9548.1)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-9548001000000000~2
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       816142004
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [71913]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-03-21 11:00:58.044 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.3 (15D21)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        D6E08775-0376-D30A-1EFE-52215D842578

Sleep/Wake UUID:       3C045728-351F-472F-BE22-318CE23CB678

Time Awake Since Boot: 74000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       5500 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 7C1002
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-9544/DVTFoundation/Protocols/DVTInvalidation.m:410
Details:  Message sent to invalidated object: <DVTScopeBarController 0x7fe52fe676e0>.

Backtrace for invalidation:
   0  0x000000010a9dc453 DVTInvalidationCoreInvalidate (in DVTFoundation)
  1  0x000000010b1fe276 -[DVTViewController invalidate] (in DVTKit)
  2  0x000000010b140edc __62-[DVTScopeBarsManager removeScopeBar:animate:completionBlock:]_block_invoke (in DVTKit)
  3  0x000000010b141aa1 -[DVTScopeBarsManager _adjustViewsForHeightOffset:animate:extraAnimations:completionBlock:] (in DVTKit)
  4  0x000000010b140d76 -[DVTScopeBarsManager removeScopeBar:animate:completionBlock:] (in DVTKit)
  5  0x000000010afdc15b -[DVTScopeBarsManager removeAllScopeBarsAnimate:] (in DVTKit)
  6  0x000000010bf3214a __91-[IDEEditorContext _openNavigableItem:documentExtension:document:shouldInstallEditorBlock:]_block_invoke (in IDEKit)
  7  0x000000010bd97c01 -[IDEEditorContext _performBlockInsideReentrantGuard:] (in IDEKit)
  8  0x000000010bd976d1 -[IDEEditorContext _openNavigableItem:documentExtension:document:shouldInstallEditorBlock:] (in IDEKit)
  9  0x000000010bdca283 -[IDEEditorContext _openNavigableItem:withContentsOfURL:documentExtension:shouldInstallEditorBlock:] (in IDEKit)
 10  0x000000010bf33ac6 -[IDEEditorContext _notifyDelegateAndOpenNavigableItem:withContentsURL:documentExtensionIdentifier:locationToSelect:annotationRepresentedObject:stateDictionary:annotationWantsIndicatorAnimation:exploreAnnotationRepresentedObject:highlightSelection:alwaysReplaceExistingNavigableItem:skipSubDocumentNavigationUnlessEditorIsReplaced:] (in IDEKit)
 11  0x000000010be08f92 -[IDEEditorContext _notifyDelegateAndOpenEditorOpenSpecifier:updateHistory:] (in IDEKit)
 12  0x000000010be08849 -[IDEEditorContext _openEditorOpenSpecifier:updateHistory:] (in IDEKit)
 13  0x000000010be086aa -[IDEEditorContext openEditorOpenSpecifier:] (in IDEKit)
 14  0x000000010be08590 -[IDEEditorModeViewController openEditorOpenSpecifier:editorContext:] (in IDEKit)
 15  0x000000010be083dc -[IDEEditorArea _openEditorOpenSpecifier:editorContext:takeFocus:] (in IDEKit)
 16  0x000000010bf71506 __108+[IDEEditorCoordinator _doOpenEditorOpenSpecifier:forWorkspaceTabController:editorContext:target:takeFocus:]_block_invoke (in IDEKit)
 17  0x000000010be0827d +[IDEEditorCoordinator _doOpenWithWorkspaceTabController:editorContext:target:allowFallback:documentURL:usingBlock:] (in IDEKit)
 18  0x000000010be07b49 +[IDEEditorCoordinator _doOpenEditorOpenSpecifier:forWorkspaceTabController:editorContext:target:takeFocus:] (in IDEKit)
 19  0x000000010be076cf -[_IDEOpenRequest _runIfNecessary] (in IDEKit)
 20  0x00007fff8efcd345 __NSFireDelayedPerform (in Foundation)
 21  0x00007fff8a9b2bc4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation)
 22  0x00007fff8a9b2853 __CFRunLoopDoTimer (in CoreFoundation)
 23  0x00007fff8aa30e6a __CFRunLoopDoTimers (in CoreFoundation)
 24  0x00007fff8a96dcd1 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 25  0x00007fff8a96d338 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 26  0x00007fff9a056935 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 27  0x00007fff9a05676f ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 28  0x00007fff9a0565af _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
 29  0x00007fff9ee500ee _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 30  0x00007fff9f21c943 -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 31  0x000000010b0ef0c2 -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 32  0x00007fff9ee45fc8 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 33  0x00007fff9edc8520 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 34  0x00007fff8beb25ad start (in libdyld.dylib)

Function: void DVTInvalidationCoreInvalidate(NSObject<DVTInvalidation> *__strong)
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fe54af099e0>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x000000010bf82279 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x000000010ab115ac _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010ab11818 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x000000010a9dc61f DVTInvalidationCoreInvalidate (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x000000010b1fe276 -[DVTViewController invalidate] (in DVTKit)
  5  0x0000000118578e63 -[IDESourceCodeEditor primitiveInvalidate] (in IDESourceEditor)
  6  0x000000010a9dc415 DVTInvalidationCoreInvalidate (in DVTFoundation)
  7  0x000000010b1fe276 -[DVTViewController invalidate] (in DVTKit)
  8  0x000000010bf32a02 __91-[IDEEditorContext _openNavigableItem:documentExtension:document:shouldInstallEditorBlock:]_block_invoke (in IDEKit)
  9  0x000000010bd97c01 -[IDEEditorContext _performBlockInsideReentrantGuard:] (in IDEKit)
 10  0x000000010bd976d1 -[IDEEditorContext _openNavigableItem:documentExtension:document:shouldInstallEditorBlock:] (in IDEKit)
 11  0x000000010bdca283 -[IDEEditorContext _openNavigableItem:withContentsOfURL:documentExtension:shouldInstallEditorBlock:] (in IDEKit)
 12  0x000000010bf33ac6 -[IDEEditorContext _notifyDelegateAndOpenNavigableItem:withContentsURL:documentExtensionIdentifier:locationToSelect:annotationRepresentedObject:stateDictionary:annotationWantsIndicatorAnimation:exploreAnnotationRepresentedObject:highlightSelection:alwaysReplaceExistingNavigableItem:skipSubDocumentNavigationUnlessEditorIsReplaced:] (in IDEKit)
 13  0x000000010be08f92 -[IDEEditorContext _notifyDelegateAndOpenEditorOpenSpecifier:updateHistory:] (in IDEKit)
 14  0x000000010be08849 -[IDEEditorContext _openEditorOpenSpecifier:updateHistory:] (in IDEKit)
 15  0x000000010be086aa -[IDEEditorContext openEditorOpenSpecifier:] (in IDEKit)
 16  0x000000010be08590 -[IDEEditorModeViewController openEditorOpenSpecifier:editorContext:] (in IDEKit)
 17  0x000000010be083dc -[IDEEditorArea _openEditorOpenSpecifier:editorContext:takeFocus:] (in IDEKit)
 18  0x000000010bf71506 __108+[IDEEditorCoordinator _doOpenEditorOpenSpecifier:forWorkspaceTabController:editorContext:target:takeFocus:]_block_invoke (in IDEKit)
 19  0x000000010be0827d +[IDEEditorCoordinator _doOpenWithWorkspaceTabController:editorContext:target:allowFallback:documentURL:usingBlock:] (in IDEKit)
 20  0x000000010be07b49 +[IDEEditorCoordinator _doOpenEditorOpenSpecifier:forWorkspaceTabController:editorContext:target:takeFocus:] (in IDEKit)
 21  0x000000010be076cf -[_IDEOpenRequest _runIfNecessary] (in IDEKit)
 22  0x00007fff8efcd345 __NSFireDelayedPerform (in Foundation)
 23  0x00007fff8a9b2bc4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation)
 24  0x00007fff8a9b2853 __CFRunLoopDoTimer (in CoreFoundation)
 25  0x00007fff8aa30e6a __CFRunLoopDoTimers (in CoreFoundation)
 26  0x00007fff8a96dcd1 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 27  0x00007fff8a96d338 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 28  0x00007fff9a056935 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 29  0x00007fff9a05676f ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 30  0x00007fff9a0565af _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
 31  0x00007fff9ee500ee _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 32  0x00007fff9f21c943 -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 33  0x000000010b0ef0c2 -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 34  0x00007fff9ee45fc8 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 35  0x00007fff9edc8520 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 36  0x00007fff8beb25ad start (in libdyld.dylib)

abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
[self isValid]

Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
1569.022036  DTXConnectionServices      0x000000010cbd93e3 initiating channel x1.c22 capability 642d65677561672d 766f72702d617461 654e2e7372656469 6174536b726f7774 0073636974736974
1569.022076  DTXConnectionServices      0x000000010cbd93e3 initiating channel x1.c21 capability 756265642e65646f 2d65677561672d67 6f72702d61746164 702e737265646976 006f666e69636f72
1606.150384  DTXConnectionServices      0x000000010cbd93e3 initiating channel x1.c20 capability 642d65677561672d 766f72702d617461 654e2e7372656469 6174536b726f7774 0073636974736974
1606.150384  DTXConnectionServices      0x000000010cbd93e3 initiating channel x1.c19 capability 756265642e65646f 2d65677561672d67 6f72702d61746164 702e737265646976 006f666e69636f72

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8cfe4002 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce565c5 pthread_kill + 90
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff9ec7e6e7 abort + 129
3   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010bf81981 +[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:assertionSignature:assertionReason:extraBacktrace:] + 1481
4   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010bf8242f -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] + 1077
5   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010ab115ac _DVTAssertionHandler + 477
6   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010ab11818 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler + 407
7   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010a9dc61f DVTInvalidationCoreInvalidate + 1098
8   com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010b1fe276 -[DVTViewController invalidate] + 464
9   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDESourceEditor    0x0000000118578e63 -[IDESourceCodeEditor primitiveInvalidate] + 3888
10  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010a9dc415 DVTInvalidationCoreInvalidate + 576
11  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010b1fe276 -[DVTViewController invalidate] + 464
12  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010bf32a02 __91-[IDEEditorContext _openNavigableItem:documentExtension:document:shouldInstallEditorBlock:]_block_invoke + 3372
13  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010bd97c01 -[IDEEditorContext _performBlockInsideReentrantGuard:] + 83
14  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010bd976d1 -[IDEEditorContext _openNavigableItem:documentExtension:document:shouldInstallEditorBlock:] + 1138
15  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010bdca283 -[IDEEditorContext _openNavigableItem:withContentsOfURL:documentExtension:shouldInstallEditorBlock:] + 2030
16  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010bf33ac6 -[IDEEditorContext _notifyDelegateAndOpenNavigableItem:withContentsURL:documentExtensionIdentifier:locationToSelect:annotationRepresentedObject:stateDictionary:annotationWantsIndicatorAnimation:exploreAnnotationRepresentedObject:highlightSelection:alwaysReplaceExistingNavigableItem:skipSubDocumentNavigationUnlessEditorIsReplaced:] + 3114
17  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010be08f92 -[IDEEditorContext _notifyDelegateAndOpenEditorOpenSpecifier:updateHistory:] + 1262
18  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010be08849 -[IDEEditorContext _openEditorOpenSpecifier:updateHistory:] + 386
19  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010be086aa -[IDEEditorContext openEditorOpenSpecifier:] + 261
20  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010be08590 -[IDEEditorModeViewController openEditorOpenSpecifier:editorContext:] + 41
21  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010be083dc -[IDEEditorArea _openEditorOpenSpecifier:editorContext:takeFocus:] + 252
22  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010bf71506 __108+[IDEEditorCoordinator _doOpenEditorOpenSpecifier:forWorkspaceTabController:editorContext:target:takeFocus:]_block_invoke + 173
23  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010be0827d +[IDEEditorCoordinator _doOpenWithWorkspaceTabController:editorContext:target:allowFallback:documentURL:usingBlock:] + 1651
24  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010be07b49 +[IDEEditorCoordinator _doOpenEditorOpenSpecifier:forWorkspaceTabController:editorContext:target:takeFocus:] + 457
25  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010be076cf -[_IDEOpenRequest _runIfNecessary] + 226
26  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8efcd345 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 377
27  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a9b2bc4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
28  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a9b2853 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1075
29  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8aa30e6a __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 298
30  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a96dcd1 __CFRunLoopRun + 1841
31  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a96d338 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
32  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff9a056935 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
33  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff9a05676f ReceiveNextEventCommon + 432
34  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff9a0565af _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
35  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9ee500ee _DPSNextEvent + 1067
36  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9f21c943 -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 454
37  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010b0ef0c2 -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 247
38  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9ee45fc8 -[NSApplication run] + 682
39  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9edc8520 NSApplicationMain + 1176
40  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff8beb25ad start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8cfe4ff6 kevent_qos + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff89b09099 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 216
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff89b08d01 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8cfde386 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8cfdd7c7 mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a96e624 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a96daec __CFRunLoopRun + 1356
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a96d338 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f00fe61 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 270
6   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x0000000113ebe5e0 -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 1103
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f15bc6f __NSThread__start__ + 1351
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce54c13 _pthread_body + 131
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce54b90 _pthread_start + 168
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce52375 thread_start + 13

Thread 3:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8cfe4176 __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a9ba16a __CFSocketManager + 762
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce54c13 _pthread_body + 131
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce54b90 _pthread_start + 168
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce52375 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8cfde386 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8cfdd7c7 mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a96e624 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a96daec __CFRunLoopRun + 1356
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a96d338 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f00fe61 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 270
6   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x0000000113eaf5c2 +[DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection startServiceBrowsers] + 213
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f15bc6f __NSThread__start__ + 1351
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce54c13 _pthread_body + 131
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce54b90 _pthread_start + 168
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce52375 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8cfde386 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8cfdd7c7 mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a96e624 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a96daec __CFRunLoopRun + 1356
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a96d338 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00007fff8d6616e9 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 412
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f15bc6f __NSThread__start__ + 1351
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce54c13 _pthread_body + 131
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce54b90 _pthread_start + 168
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce52375 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8cfde386 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8cfdd7c7 mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a96e624 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a96daec __CFRunLoopRun + 1356
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a96d338 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9ef0f065 _NSEventThread + 149
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce54c13 _pthread_body + 131
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce54b90 _pthread_start + 168
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce52375 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:: DYMobileDeviceManager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8cfde386 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8cfdd7c7 mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a96e624 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a96daec __CFRunLoopRun + 1356
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a96d338 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f00fe61 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 270
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f081afd -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 74
7   com.apple.GPUToolsMobileFoundation  0x000000011da43071 -[DYMobileDeviceManager _deviceNotificationThread:] + 134
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f15bc6f __NSThread__start__ + 1351
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce54c13 _pthread_body + 131
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce54b90 _pthread_start + 168
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce52375 thread_start + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8cfe3eb2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce55150 _pthread_cond_wait + 767
2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000011398d50b -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 450
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f15bc6f __NSThread__start__ + 1351
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce54c13 _pthread_body + 131
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce54b90 _pthread_start + 168
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce52375 thread_start + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8cfe3eb2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce55150 _pthread_cond_wait + 767
2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000011398d50b -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 450
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f15bc6f __NSThread__start__ + 1351
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce54c13 _pthread_body + 131
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce54b90 _pthread_start + 168
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce52375 thread_start + 13

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8cfe3eb2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce55150 _pthread_cond_wait + 767
2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000011398d50b -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 450
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f15bc6f __NSThread__start__ + 1351
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce54c13 _pthread_body + 131
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce54b90 _pthread_start + 168
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce52375 thread_start + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8cfe3eb2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce55150 _pthread_cond_wait + 767
2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000011398d50b -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 450
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f15bc6f __NSThread__start__ + 1351
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce54c13 _pthread_body + 131
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce54b90 _pthread_start + 168
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce52375 thread_start + 13

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8cfe3eb2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce55150 _pthread_cond_wait + 767
2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000011398d50b -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 450
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f15bc6f __NSThread__start__ + 1351
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce54c13 _pthread_body + 131
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce54b90 _pthread_start + 168
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce52375 thread_start + 13

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8cfde386 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8cfdd7c7 mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a96e624 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a96daec __CFRunLoopRun + 1356
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a96d338 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8aa301f1 CFRunLoopRun + 97
6   com.apple.DebugSymbols          0x00007fff9a74169a SpotlightQueryThread(void*) + 346
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce54c13 _pthread_body + 131
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce54b90 _pthread_start + 168
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce52375 thread_start + 13

Thread 14:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.dt.Xcode.IBAnnotationProviderIndexQueryQueue
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8cfde3da semaphore_timedwait_trap + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff89b0b58d _dispatch_group_wait_slow + 154
2   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x0000000117ba7281 -[IBIndexClassDescriber makeIndexCallUsingBlock:] + 204
3   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x0000000117ba7437 -[IBIndexClassDescriber performThrottledIndexQuery:] + 171
4   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x0000000117ba825c -[IBIndexClassDescriber relationSymbolsInClassNamed:ofRelationshipType:] + 184
5   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x00000001179771ec -[IBAnnotationIndexProvider annotationsFromIndex] + 443
6   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x0000000117977577 +[IBAnnotationIndexProvider annotationsForClassesNamed:usingIndexClassDescriber:] + 121
7   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x000000011797aeca __52-[IBAnnotationProvider rebuildAnnotationsUsingIndex]_block_invoke + 44
8   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010ab4d8f8 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 153
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff89b0e871 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff89b0333f _dispatch_client_callout + 8
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff89b07f6f _dispatch_queue_drain + 754
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff89b0e63b _dispatch_queue_invoke + 549
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff89b0333f _dispatch_client_callout + 8
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff89b071cf _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1890
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff89b06a34 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce5468f _pthread_wqthread + 1129
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8ce52365 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 15:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.xcode.indexer.connection
0   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00007fff91be79cf sqlite3BtreeMovetoUnpacked + 351
1   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00007fff91bd490d sqlite3VdbeExec + 35693
2   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00007fff91bcaa8f sqlite3_step + 591
3   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010b54ce52 -[IDEIndexDBConnection runSQLiteStmt:sql:bindings:forEachRow:whenDone:] + 375
4   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010b5f9b04 __50-[IDEIndexDBConnection doSQLChanges:withBindings:]_block_invoke + 126
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff89b0333f _dispatch_client_callout + 8
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff89b11a9b _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 856
7   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010ab4d7b0 DVTDispatchSync + 62
8   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010b54e2bf -[IDEIndexDBConnection doSQLChanges:withBindings:] + 220
9   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010b54e177 -[IDEIndexDBTempTable insertSQLChanges:withBindings:] + 149
10  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010b56ac0a -[IDEIndexDatabaseQueryProvider membersMatchingKinds:forInterfaces:forIndex:] + 315
11  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010b56aa92 -[IDEIndex(IDEIndexQueries) membersMatchingKinds:forInterfaces:] + 101
12  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x0000000117ba6390 __100-[IBExternallySynchronizedIndexClassDescriber relationSymbolsInIndexClassSymbol:ofRelationshipType:]_block_invoke + 154
13  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x00000001142c858a -[NSMutableDictionary(IBMutableDictionaryAdditions) ib_objectForKey:creatingIfNecessaryWithBlock:] + 83
14  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x00000001142c8666 -[NSMutableDictionary(IBMutableDictionaryAdditions) ib_objectForKey:inDictionaryForKey:creatingIfNecessaryWithBlock:] + 153
15  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x0000000117ba6232 -[IBExternallySynchronizedIndexClassDescriber relationSymbolsInIndexClassSymbol:ofRelationshipType:] + 253
16  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x0000000117ba64f1 -[IBExternallySynchronizedIndexClassDescriber relationSymbolsInClassNamed:ofRelationshipType:] + 107
17  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x0000000117ba74d6 __52-[IBIndexClassDescriber performThrottledIndexQuery:]_block_invoke + 16
18  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010ab4e812 __DVTDispatchGroupAsync_block_invoke + 153
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff89b0e871 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff89b0333f _dispatch_client_callout + 8
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff89b07f6f _dispatch_queue_drain + 754
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff89b0e63b _dispatch_queue_invoke + 549
```

Comment: Is your /etc/hosts file ok? https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6100778?tstart=0

Comment: @eddie not sure of that, since this error not appear again, and I use XCode 7.3.1 now.  And I remember that my crash is related to carthage.

Comment: ok so you solved the issue. If you remember how, please consider writing a small answer for the community.

Comment: but I'm not sure of that, is that OK?

Comment: if you are not sure, at least edit your original post with what you think was the solution.

Comment: yes, I posed the possible answer, if got enough up, maybe can make is as answer.

Comment: That's the spirit! :)

Comment: @eddie Thank you for your edit update.

Comment: @JerrZhou your are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I'm not sure of that if I resolved my crash or not by fix root cause.

I just try to use **"carthage bootstrap --platform ios --use-submodules --no-use-binaries --no-build"** instead of using **"carthage bootstrap --platform ios --use-submodules --no-use-binaries"**.  and include the subproject into my project.

And build all the sub-project by run Xcode.